# Get survey respondent list after a specific date

Tags: surveymonkey

I have a small question regarding the use of survey monkey api. I am using C# for my development. Is there any way that I can query a respondent list so that I can get all the respondents after a specific date. I can actually get all the list of respondents and compare with the startModifiedDate but I am trying to pass the query to the api so that I get only the required data. Is there any way to do this?

Thank you,
Rakesh Vankadaru

Answer (score 1):

There is a 'start_date' parameter you can include in the API request, to filter the set of respondents to only those created after that date:

https://developer.surveymonkey.com/mashery/get_respondent_list

Answer (score 0):

As Ryan mentioned in his comment, you can use `start_date` to limit the respondents you get to all those who started answering a survey after a certain date & time. It's important to note that using `start_date` just limits the list to when the response was started. If the respondent hasn't completed the survey when you check for responses, there could still be more responses coming. It's also possible to configure your collector so that users can edit their answers. In either case, the `start_date` for the respondent won't change.

A better option is to use `date_modified` since that will change each time new questions are answered or existing answers are updated. That method is demonstrated [here](https://github.com/SurveyMonkey/python_guides/blob/master/guides/polling.py).

Comment: This is the thing I wanted to know. Thank you for the complete explanation and this is the important thing to know 'date_modified'.